# Maass forms as sections of line bundles?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

One way of obtained modular forms are as global sections of line bundle on the modular surface. On the other hand, I have not seen Maass forms constructed this way. (Though there is some work does this for harmonic weak Maass forms) What is the reason for this?

Comment: The line bundle in the theory of holomorphic modular forms is a way to keep track of the nontrivial (but highly interesting) way in which they transform under the modular group. Maass forms are actually invariant under the modular group, so they are sections of the trivial bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I have heard this statement somewhere before; but what about the weight k-Maass forms?